# Simple Definition of Random Variable X>Y

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

For nonnegative RVs, one can say that if X>Y, then E(X)>E(Y). Now the proof of this is using a simple RV Z, Z>X s.t. E(Z)$\ge$E(x)-$\epsilon$.

I have two simple questions about the definition and proof:

1) What does it mean for X$<$Y? Does it mean stochastically less or greater?  i.e. X1 is stochastically larger in than X2 if $P(X1>t)≥P(X2>t)$, Or does it mean X is strictly smaller than Y for all w's.

2) And is $\epsilon$ all positive $\epsilon$>0 in this proof? then how can we gaurantee to find such a simple Z in this proof? I suppose this is related to nonnegative RV's definition but I do not understand the definiton of nonnegative RVs. E(X)+sup{EZ, simple Z $Ω \to I\!R$, Z$\le$X} so I assume X can be continuous here right? than can anyone explain this definition and give me a simple example? I am confused since again beacuse of what Z$\le$X means.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $X<Y$ in this context usually means in an almost sure sense, i.e. $P(X<Y)=1$

Comment: yea but a.s. means X<Y for all events so X is strictly smaller than Y? like if Y is {2,3,4} X has to be smaller than 2?

Comment: More like $X(\omega)<Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$, the sample space.

Comment: how is that not the same as strictly smaller (unless X and Y are dependent)? and can ou please tell me if the example i mentioned is correct in my above comment

Comment: Yes, if $Y(\omega)=2$ then $X(\omega)<2$ for some $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: why not for all? im a little confused about your definition of X(ω)<Y(ω) here sorry